# Series/Films-related tags

Tags: discussion, tags

It was already discussed that questions related to series, films, etc. are accepted. However, tags that are related to series are far more too specific for us. They are often related to one single question. Using [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/441980/list-tags-per-question-number), I could find the following

- [dexter](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dexter)
- [stargate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate)
- [conan-the-barbarian](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conan-the-barbarian)
- [sims](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims)
- [facebook](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)
- [cthulhu](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cthulhu)
- [star-wars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars)

Note that I might have missed some others.

I would support a direct removal of those, but I'd rather have your point of view on that.

Comment: I agree burn em.

Comment: They are now all dead. May they rest in pieces...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with one exception.

Tags should describe the question and also allow people with relevant expertise to find that question or filter it. It's unlikely that dexter or conan-the-barbarian expertise will be specific enough to warrant a tag.

The only exception is cthulhu which I think is worth keeping just because the cthulhu mythos is extensive and a lot of things have been written based on or using the mythos or ideas from the mythos. I'd say cthulhu is now closer to a genre a la steampunk rather than being a specific series.

Comment: I agree. But maybe we should introduce a "series-based" (or something similar) tag, much like the "sience-based" tag, for questions that need their answers to comply to a specific fandom or media-universe

Comment: I think something like "follow-canon" or similar tag might be a better name for that case - I'm not convinced it would be useful though. It's both simpler and clearer to put it as a comment.

Comment: The use I imagine is, that it would make questions easier to exclude in a search. E.g. if I am interested in answering questions on history, but I am not interested in questions where I need to know about a specific TV series' storyline, I could exclude this tag from my searches.

Comment: It's a valid use-case. Suggest it in a meta post and see if people like it :) I've got mixed feelings myself since it wouldn't identify what TV show you need to know about...

Comment: I will do so after a consent is found for this question. I can see your concerns, and I guess that this is the problem that led to *this* question.

Comment: ...wait so you think there is more cthulhu mythos than star wars?!?  The expanded universe is...shall we go with voluminous.

Comment: Well, I disagree with creating a tag, which has as main purpose to filter **out** questions. That's not what tags are made for.

Comment: And for the Cthulhu, in French, we have a name for such litterary genre, [fantastique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastique). Learning from Wikipedia, apparently there are none in English. Anyway, Bram Stocker's short stories and Poe's to some extend, are close to Lovecraft's. But none fit within a Cthulhu tag. Similarly that Star Wars could go to Space-opera. So if we keep something to indicate that genre, I think it should be renamed.

Comment: @James Star wars is a specific (if large) example of a larger fantasy in space genre. You wouldn't use the Star Wars tag for Firefly for example. Cthulhu is used more generically to describe existential horror. However on reflection I'm starting to think you may be right. Either we keep all of them or delete all of them.

Comment: I am just playing devil's advocate...heh...that's funny, anyway.  I see your point about cthulhu but I feel like keeping some and getting rid of others would just create confusion even if you make a good argument for keeping one.